# Unable to view 2 local sites over network

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I have 2 websites running on my local machine that I'd like to view from other machines on the same network.

For /etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site1.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/answers/app/webroot
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  <Directory "/var/www/answers/app/webroot">
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all    
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

For /etc/apache2/sites-available/site2.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site2.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/answers2/app/webroot
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  <Directory "/var/www/answers2/app/webroot">
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all    
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have added 2 entries in the /etc/hosts file as:

```
127.0.0.1    site1.com
127.0.0.1    site2.com
```

Now, when I point the browser on my machine to site1.com, it shows me the first site and pointing the browser to site2.com, it shows me the second site.

However,when I type in the local IP of my machine in the browser, it always shows site2. How can I change it to switch between site1 and site2 ? Is there a way that I can view both the sites form another machine (esp. mobile devices over wireless network) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the *other machine* you would ordinarily add corresponding entries to the machines host file (as you have done on your machine) - pointing to the local IP address of your web server.

```
192.168.XXX.XXX  site1.com
192.168.XXX.XXX  site2.com
```

However, unless your mobile device (eg. phone?) is rooted, then you probably don't have access to the hosts file.

I think the ultimate/correct solution is to run a local DNS server:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9633/manually-set-a-hostname-for-ip-address-i-e-etc-hosts-equiv

However, you *might* be able to do this if your device supports an Ad Hoc network:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26692/connect-to-laptops-localhost-websites

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I shall take a look at the links that you suggested. For now, I have modified the hosts file settings for site1 to *:80 and site2 to 127.0.0.1:80. That way, I can view site1 on my mobile device by typing the local IP. Since I just need to check site1 on the mobile device, it works for me for now.